# Gridview With Fixed Header and Column

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview and i have set a fixed header but the width of the columns in the gridview does not align with the column of the header.

```
  <div style="width:1000px;border:1px solid #084B8A;color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;">
    <table style="color:#3090C7;">
        <tr>
            <td style ="width:120px;">Item_ID</td>
            <td style ="width:200px;">Category</td>
            <td style ="width:300px;">ItemName</td>
            <td style ="width:120px;">Pack_Size</td>
            <td style ="width:200px;">CostPrice</td>
            <td style ="width:200px;">SalesPrice</td>
            <td style ="width:150px;">Stock</td>
            <td style ="width:150px;">Reorder</td>
            <td style ="width:200px;">Barcode</td>
            <td style ="width:200px;">Barcode2</td>
            <td style ="width:200px;">Barcode3</td>
            <td style ="width:200px;">Barcode4</td>
            <td style ="width:200px;">Item_Discontinued</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div style ="height:300px; width:1000px; overflow:auto;" >
        <asp:GridView ID="GrdItemList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        ShowHeader = "false" Width ="1000px" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#BFE4FF" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "120px" DataField="Item_ID" HeaderText="Item_ID" 
/>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "200px" DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" 
/>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "300px" DataField="ItemName" HeaderText="ItemName" 
/>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "120px" DataField="Pack_Size" 
HeaderText="Pack_Size" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "200px" DataField="CostPrice" 
HeaderText="CostPrice" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "200px" DataField="SalesPrice" 
 HeaderText="SalesPrice" />
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField="Stock" HeaderText="Stock" />
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField="Reorder" HeaderText="Reorder" 
/>
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "200px" DataField="Barcode" HeaderText="Barcode" 
/>
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "200px" DataField="Barcode2" 
HeaderText="Barcode2" />
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "200px" DataField="Barcode3" 
HeaderText="Barcode3" />
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "200px" DataField="Barcode4" 
HeaderText="Barcode4" />
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "200px" DataField="Item_Discontinued" 
   HeaderText="Item_Discontinued" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
 </div>
```

I want the output to be that if the header of say 'ItemID' is 50px, the column in the gridview holding the 'ItemID' also should be exact 50px and not overlapping.

Comment: Why add a table for the headers, when you can just add a ````HeaderText```` property to the BoundFields and let the GridView handle itself?

Comment: And this is more of a CSS issue than it is a GridView or VB.Net.  The GridView is behaving like it should.

Comment: @JohnPete22, I want the header not to be scrollable.

Comment: When you say scrollable, you mean horizontally? Because I'm not really sure how a header can scroll vertically unless the Text is long and also based on your screens resolution on what it will display.

Comment: The header will scroll vertically along if the header of the gridview is used

Comment: Try this...remove some of the columns in the GridView and see if it still scrolls. I've never had an issue with any of my GridView headers scrolling, but then again I've never used this many columns in a GridView.

Comment: Just another observation, you are setting the Width of the GridView to 1000px, but then the sum of all the BoundField Widths exceeds that value.

Comment: The scroll bar is most likely happening because you have the width setting specified and then you have ````overflow:auto```` which will cause the scrolling to happen.  Link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: the Gridview is working as expected. My point is, If i make the ShowHeader=True, and i remove the table. Once i scroll the gridview vertically down, the header will also scroll up. I want a way that once i scroll vertically down, the header text will stick so that if i have like 2000 records, if i scroll to record 987, i should still be able to see the header like ItemID, Category, ItemName...

Comment: Paging? As a user, do you really want to scroll 987 rows down?  That doesn't seem like ideal UI...20 - 50 rows is enough to process. But if you're stuck on this implementation, I would again recommending adding the tag CSS as well, because this is more of a CSS issue than the GridView misbehaving.